Anthology of comic illustrated horror and fantasy comics, one was werewolves pre 1985
Anthology of comic illustrated horror and fantasy comics, one was werewolves pre 1985
Wasn’t a magazine as my public school library had it and I read it many times. Graduated there in 1986 so the book was before that. The only story I remember I think was werewolf one with comic art similar to that in Heavy Metal. I vaguely recall the story as being a little gory and I think it had a twist ending / reveal.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe any of the characters or remember any names?

Unfortunately no I’m trying to remember other stories in the book but this was 40 years ago
